# How to add External Bibtex File to Autocompletion List in Texstudio?

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio, auto-completion

I recently generated a large separate Bibtex file with all the references I ever should need. I use Texstudio to type my Latex documents, which has the advantage that it suggests commands.

The question I now have, is the following: How to add the entries of the separate Bibtex file to the list of autocomplete suggestions? I already tried in the preferences under Adv. Editor to add the additional search path user/Desktop/Latex/Bibliography. However this did not work. What should I do? Should the additional search path be in a different form?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything extra apart from loading the `.bib` in your current project, so you can use its references. TeXstudio automatically suggests all `bibid`s for all entries in the loaded files when typing `\cite`-like commands.

`.bib` file:

[image]

`.tex` file with autocompletion:

[image]

---

This should work no matter how you load the file, even if it's an absolute path as in your example:

[image]